# Registry doesn't publish ownship?

Tags: domains

I thought that all registries were required to publish ownership, or some kind of information, even if it is their own information. But when I search this on the whois registry http://whois.domaintools.com/org.kp it says it doesn't publish ownership or any kind of information.
What registry's offer this service? And how do they get away with it? I cannot find this service anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is North Korea- mostly the government of North Korea. KP is the (country code) ccTLD. This (org.kp) is not actually a site but a sub-domain of a ccTLD for organization.

Not every site has to have public contact information- hence private registrations. However, there are some rules that some level of contact information must be present that are sometimes ignored and not enforced.

Somewhere around 12 years ago, enforcement of Internet rules has waned somewhat right or wrong. It is what it is.

Comment: Who offers this service?  I mean this isnt the first time I've ran crossed this, and the last time it wasn't North Korea.   This is totally private, no IP or company name.  If I registered a private domain at Godaddy it would have Godaddys name and IP address

Comment: nevermind I see how they hide it.

Comment: @AlexWan That is because it is a TLD and a sub-domain of the TLD. ***I agree that there should be contact information.*** But it is not quite the same as a website.